# Chromium based Browser "slimjet" toolbar grafical resources (icons)

Tags: icons, toolbar, chromium

I want to modifiy slimjet for personal use and searched through gits, reshacked all dll files and the app exe but I can't seem to find the resources I want to change. Does anybody know, where the grafical resoucres - icons or buttons for the toolbar - are stored in chromium derivatives general, but especially slimjet? I am not talking about the extension buttons. I mean those for "home" and navigation.
Are they inside the compiled binary file inside the exe or inside the .pak file I can not reshack or unpack?

Any clue or hint or help is appreciated.